# Applying Audio Effect to Entire Project

Tags: audio, final-cut-pro-x, workflow

I'm working on a project made of hundreds of short video clips taken over the past year.  Some indoor clips, some outdoor, some in a quiet environment, some in loud, etc.  Naturally, they all have different "loudness" to them.  Some have quiet conversations, some have loud clapping or whatever.

What I'd like is to amplify all clips uniformly (like apply a gain of 5db or so) but without making the already-loud moments overly loud.  I've read about the Limiter Logic effect, and I see there's also Compressor, Adaptive Limiter, etc.

Is Final Cut's "analyze audio" feature good enough for this?  Or does that not deal with the already loud areas?  I can create a compound clip for the entire project, and apply Limiter to that, but is there a better way?

Comment: what I've done is just copy a clip in the timeline with some "analyze audio" features, and the Limiter audio effect enabled, then manually use "Paste Attributes" to paste the effects to other clips.  it still seems like there ought to be a single master audio track somewhere i could apply effects to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I use it primarily and did not have problems.
Start with the Compressor to bring all sounds together. If necessary have a limiter at the end.